# Заблокировать всю cеть IP-адресов по которым отказы более 99%?

Tags: seo, бот, продвижение

Сервер Ubuntu. На нем работают пара десятков сайтов.

Основной источник трафика - переходы из поисковых систем (99%).
Процент отказа по ним 30-40%.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Все бы хорошо, но в последнее время наблюдаю неистовый интерес ко многим сайтам на сервере со стороны неких устройств: судя по Яндекс метрике осуществляются прямые заходы на мой сайт продолжительностью 0 сек. Соответственно в вебвизоре такие посещения помечаются как недоступные к просмотру.

Доходит до того, что доля таких визитов в общей массе превышает половину всех заходов на сайт.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Далее график посетителей (только прямые заходы на сайт):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

График отказов (прямые заходы)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В итоге ухудшаются показатели "среднее время на сайте", "средняя глубина просмотра", возможно еще какие-то.

Хотя я сомневаюсь, большой процент отказов по прямым заходам, скажется на трафик из поиска (я надеюсь яндекс и Гугл различают эти два вида трафика при 
ранжировании сайта).

Далее я выявил IP-адреса, с которых происходят такие "плохие" визиты:

```
116.203.104.*
116.203.115.*
116.203.24.*
116.203.78.*
116.203.79.*
116.203.99.*
79.137.130.*
89.208.198.*
89.208.198.*
89.208.199.*
89.208.84.*
89.208.85.*
89.208.86.*
89.208.87.*
```

Сервис xseo.in/ips говорит от том, что это следующие товарищи(Информация GEOIP/IPGEO):

```
DE(Germany) Hetzner Online GmbH
RU(Russia) Mrgroup Investments Limited
RU(Russia) St Petersburg Limited liability company Mail.Ru
```

Проследил параметры визитов с этих IP-адресов. Обнаружил, что userAgent-ы по ним очень часто меняются (и маскируются под обычных пользователей). Поэтому фильтрация по userAgent - невозможна.

Теперь возник вопрос: **А может просто забанить все эти подсети?** Толку-то от них? Только создают дополнительную нагрузку на сервер. И портят общую картину посещаемости сайтов.

Странно, что яндекс метрика считает эти визиты на сайт пользовательскими...

P.S. Дополнительно фильтрую запросы от таких ботов как MegaIndex, MJ12bot, SemrushBot и прочих по их userAgent на уровне apache, благо они не скрываются и 
прописывают открыто себя в этих параметрах.

Answer (score 1):

Давным давно в SEO-оптимизации, хочу сказать следующее по этой проблеме:

- Чем больше ресурс тем больше сервисов будут тебя посещать (мусорные, парсеры, гео и т.д.).
- Мы пробовали заморачиваться и ручками заносить в черный список "мусорные ip", в итоге это превратилось в перманентный процесс, оказалось не рентабельно столько времени на это тратить. Но если это вопрос нескольких десятков IP - пробуйте руками. Делать это нужно вдумчиво т.к. можно забанить ip реальных людей.
- Пришли к выводу, что лучше нарашивать трафик реальных пользователей. В вашем случае отфильтровывайте приямые заходы все. Использовать другие метрики эффективности вместо прямых заходов.